# GUI python: pedido de dicas de interface e ou ide's para isso

Tags: python-3.x, gui

Eu estou refazendo um pequeno projeto que tinha feito em Java, mas agora em Python. Estou aprendendo tudo do zero e sozinho.

Preciso de ajuda com essa parte. Qual interface vocês recomendam? Tem alguma IDE que trabalhe em modo design e coisas assim?

Até o momento, só ouvi falar de TKinter através de algumas playlist no youtube: [Ignorância Zero - playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfCKf0-awunOu2WyLe2pSD2fXUo795xRe) e [Excript - playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLesCEcYj003QxPQ4vTXkt22-E11aQvoVj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TKinter é o "denominador comum" de interface gráfica para Python. Isto significa que um script Python que faça uso de TK rodará em qualquer plataforma. Para aplicativos simples, é uma boa escolha, mas até onde sei não há um "designer" para TK, você tem de especificar a interface usando código.

Para projetos pequenos ele é suficiente e fácil de usar. Para um projeto grande com pretensões de portabilidade teria de considerar opções como Qt (PyQt). Outras opções como PyGTK podem ser convenientes se você já conhece GTK+, mas GTK+ fora do Linux não é tão conveniente de usar. PyObjC é specífico do Mac, e assim por diante.

Comment: É exatamente o que eu tô querendo: opções.

Comment: Apenas um pequeno adendo relacionado a GTK+. Caso escolha fazer uso dele, esqueça o PyGtk, ele é baseado em Gtk2 que já foi descontinuado. Para Gtk o caminho é [PyGobjects](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)